# Toggle Editing Mode issue with QGIS 2.8

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, editing

Returning to QGIS after a long absence.

Probably missing something basic, but I can't click on the Toggle Editing Mode (pen symbol) when I open an Attribute Table in QGIS 2.8.

Any pointers?

Comment: What is the source of the attribute table you're attempting to edit (shapefile, FGDB, etc)? Do you have write access to it? By can't click on I assume you mean it's grayed out? Does the keyboard shortcut (ctrl E) also not work?

Comment: It would help to **edit** the question to contain the operating system in use and a screen-shot of the problem.